# Enforcing the maxlength attribute on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, maxlength

I have an a text input with a maximum length:

```
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50">
```

This has been working fine on all the desktop browsers I've tried, but the maximum length does not seem to be enforced on mobile browsers.

Is there any way to get mobile browsers to enforce `maxlength`? I am open to using JavaScript and/or jQuery in the solution.

Comment: I strongly suspect there's something else at play. Are you using any libraries or frameworks with turn your markup into something different for mobile browsers, such as jQuery Mobile?

Comment: I would second what @MattBall said. Probably a script conflicting or throwing errors. Do you see any js errors thrown?

Comment: You can use http://mimo84.github.io/bootstrap-maxlength/ which looks like having a `validate` parameter for browsers non supporting the maxLength attribute, including mobiles.

Comment: I only have the regular jQuery library included. I even tested it out on w3schools page about maxlength. It doesn't work on my phone at least

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var $input = $('input')
$input.keyup(function(e) {
    var max = 5;
    if ($input.val().length > max) {
        $input.val($input.val().substr(0, max));
    }
});
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fttk2/1/

Comment: Is it possible to disable the key press after it reaches maximum 5 ?

Comment: @DineshKumar One of the other responses disables key presses after reaching the maximum. However, it's not recommended since the user will then be unable to press backspace.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is because predictive text is enabled on your keyboard, disable it and try again

Comment: Sure, but you can't assume every user is going to have this disabled. You have to be able to account for all instances.

Comment: @mdurchholz Of course, I just wanted friends to know why this happened, maybe it will help a better search to find the final answer,I also had this problem today, but I did not find a good answer to it

Comment: @VajihehHabibi I didn't find the right fix for this using only javascript. But your comment show me the problem. Tks

Comment: Even if predictive text is enabled, it'll cut the amount off to the actual maxlength as soon as you complete or cancel the predictive text.

Answer (score 2):

```
var max = 1

input.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    event.target.value = event.target.value.substring(0, max)
})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something a bit more simple. The aboves didn't work for me unless there was a space added for the field to pick up on it... or if I hit submit right after, it still passed the information.

```
if($(".input") > 20){$(".input") = input.slice(0,20)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Universal jQuery way to enforce the stated `maxlength` of a form field. (I needed it for sessionStorage, localStorage, and param overrides.) Code optimized for readability.

```
$('input').on('change', function () {
  var max = $(this).attr('maxlength'),
      val = $(this).val(),
      trimmed;

  if (max && val) {
    trimmed = val.substr(0, max);
    $(this).val(trimmed);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because predictive text is enabled on your mobile keyboard so disable predictive text.

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" type="text" name="name" maxlength="50">
```

Comment: This did not prevent my mobile keyboard from generating predictions. Seems like JS is the only solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
var maxLength = 10;
var field = $('#myinput');
field.keydown( function(e)
{
    if ( $(this).val().length >= maxLength ) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Can't seem to hit backspace once the max length has been reached.